# How to Initialize bronto.sca.cart object with Bronto JSON

Tags: javascript, json, bronto

I am using bronto Tag manager to track the cart details.

I have included Bronto Commerce JavaScript snippet in my page.
Now I can create **bronto.sca** object.

**bronto.sca.config()** and **bronto.sca.id** is returning values.

But **bronto.sca.cart** always returns null.

This is the code I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#Run").click(function()
   {
       alert('Run clicked');
       debugger;
       bronto.init;

      var brontoCart = {
          "cartPhase": "ORDER_REVIEW",
          "currency": "USD",
          "subtotal":990.00,
          "discountAmount": 0,
          "taxAmount": 110.00,
          "grandTotal": 880.00,
           "orderId": "1331",
           "emailAddress": "Footer@qwe.vo",
           "cartUrl": "http://localhost:5000/cart#view",
          "lineItems": new Array()
        };
       bronto.sca.addToCart(brontoCart);
     });

</script>

<script data-name="__br_tm" type="text/javascript">
var _bsw = _bsw || [];
_bsw.push(['_bswId', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx']);
(function() {
var bsw = document.createElement('script'); bsw.type ='text/javascript';    bsw.async = true;
bsw.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'js.bronto.com/c/********************/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/s/b.min.js';
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; t.parentNode.insertBefore(bsw, t);
})();
```

Also, how to add bronto json in a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for documentation on how you're supposed to construct the Bronto JSON object -- closest I could get is https://helpdocs.bronto.com/bmp/#task/t_bmp_home_settings_commerce_cart_selector_map_json.html

I didn't configure it in Bronto but I did set up a JSON object which gets automatically tracked, so I think my implementation is slightly different.  In my case, you don't actually need to "do" anything to register a cart once you've configured *in Bronto* what variable to look for, per http://app.bronto.com/mail/pref/commerce/ (emphasis mine)

> Note: The Order Capture JavaScript is NOT needed if you implemented the Bronto JSON on your site.
>   To track conversions and orders, construct a JavaScript object using data from your site and **pass it to Bronto using the `bronto.orders.send` function, wrapped in a listener for the "bronto.commerce.ready" event as shown in the example below**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("bronto.commerce.ready", function() {
    bronto.orders.send({
  "customerOrderId": 12345,
  "emailAddress": "name@example.com",
```

In your case, it looks like you're just using the wrong "call" to send your cart (the emphasized part).

Otherwise, I think the JSON object is declared as the "shadowDiv1" entry in your cart view per the initial help link

> shadowDiv1
>   Enter in the variable name of a JavaScript object to render hidden to the current page.